# Impact of XmlContentCheckForDiskChanges in umbraco 6/7

Tags: umbraco, umbraco6, umbraco7

What is impact of configuration option:

```
<!-- Update in-memory cache if xml file is changed -->
<XmlContentCheckForDiskChanges>False</XmlContentCheckForDiskChanges>
```

**Questions I have in mind**

- Does this impact performance and how?
- Does it improve it?
- Does it cause app recycle everything this happens?

Documentation does not provide much useful help. (http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Using-Umbraco/Config-files/umbracoSettings/)